# Compute the mean of the interval around the exact hour in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with timestamps as index, the data has a frequency of 10 minutes.

I can't find a way to compute the mean in a interval from `h - 30min` to `h + 30min`, where `h` are all the exact hours (o'clock hours).

```
In[1]: date_index = pd.date_range('2015-12-01 00:00:00', freq='10Min', periods=70)
       df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(70), index= date_index, columns=['Data'])
       df.head(10)

Out[1]:                  Data
2015-12-01 00:00:00  0.653885
2015-12-01 00:10:00  0.605046
2015-12-01 00:20:00  0.438547
2015-12-01 00:30:00  0.062426
2015-12-01 00:40:00  0.415468
2015-12-01 00:50:00  0.458047
2015-12-01 01:00:00  0.523140
2015-12-01 01:10:00  0.736519
2015-12-01 01:20:00  0.934904
2015-12-01 01:30:00  0.799523
```

I was thinking in using a for loop with df.index as range, and look for every exact hour, and then compute the mean for a the interval around the specific hour, but I can't find an easy way of indexing the data around the hour. Is there an easy way of doing this in Pandas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about the exact expected output here but you can first resample the data every half and hour and find rolling mean to get the mean of 1.5 Hrs period.

```
df.resample('30T').mean().rolling(3, center = True).mean()

    Data
2015-12-01 00:00:00 NaN
2015-12-01 00:30:00 0.419649
2015-12-01 01:00:00 0.427544
2015-12-01 01:30:00 0.414868
2015-12-01 02:00:00 0.545400
2015-12-01 02:30:00 0.643669
2015-12-01 03:00:00 0.626265
2015-12-01 03:30:00 0.581142
2015-12-01 04:00:00 0.508442
2015-12-01 04:30:00 0.511635
2015-12-01 05:00:00 0.452952
2015-12-01 05:30:00 0.473471
2015-12-01 06:00:00 0.400974
2015-12-01 06:30:00 0.358676
2015-12-01 07:00:00 0.244290
2015-12-01 07:30:00 0.343688
2015-12-01 08:00:00 0.456954
2015-12-01 08:30:00 0.548263
2015-12-01 09:00:00 0.431159
2015-12-01 09:30:00 0.378981
2015-12-01 10:00:00 0.407988
2015-12-01 10:30:00 0.496860
2015-12-01 11:00:00 0.508232
2015-12-01 11:30:00 NaN
```